# How to write xml into a file using MarkupBuilder

Tags: java, xml, groovy, markupbuilder

I created an xml using MarkupBuilder in groovy but how do i write it into a xml file in my project dir `E:\tomcat 5.5\webapps\csm\include\xml`

```
def writer = new StringWriter()
    def xml = new MarkupBuilder(writer)
    String[] splitted

    xml.rows()
    {   for(int i=0;i<lines.length-1;i++){
            row()
            {
                for(int j=0;j<lines[i].length();j++)
                {
                     splitted= lines[i].split(',');
                }
                name(splitted[0])
                email(splitted[1])

            }
        }
    }
```

here `println writer.toString()` prints my whole xml content but i need it in a file in my tomcat project's  `xml` directory

Comment: Use a java.io.FileWriter

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of using a `StringWriter`, use a `FileWriter`. Also use system property `catalina.base` to get the Tomcat homepath.

```
def writer = new FileWriter(new File(System.getProperty("catalina.base") + "/webapps/csm/include/xml/yourfile.xml"))
```

Note however that it's not the best place to save your runtime generated files. They will be deleted every time you redeploy your `.war` file.

Comment: Thanks I managed to get an answer by myself first, see my answer too, but i'll give it to you :)

Answer (score 6):

Not to take away from the correct answers above, but you can make your code **much** more `Groovy`:

```
new File( "${System.properties['catalina.base']}/webapps/csm/include/xml/yourfile.xml" ).withWriter { writer ->
  def xml = new MarkupBuilder( writer )

  xml.rows {
    lines.each { line ->
      row {
        def splitted = line.split( ',' )
        name( splitted[0] )
        email( splitted[1] )
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
new File('E:\tomcat 5.5\webapps\csm\include\xml\Foo.xml') << writer.toString()
```

Not sure if you need to double escape `\\` file path on windoze...

Comment: I cannot give an absolute path, i am not sure how to provide relative path for `E:\tomcat 5.5\webapps\csm\include\xml` dir because i will be using this in a linux box too

Comment: at runtime can you not set the path based on OS? path = win? 'E:\..' : '/linux/tomcat/dir'

Comment: no that is not possible here, i used `../webapps/csm/include/xml/data.xml` instead and it works as i used `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to set my path to tomcat bin directory

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `StringWriter` i used `FileWriter`

and as for the the path i did

```
def writer = new FileWriter("../webapps/csm/include/xml/data.xml" )
```

Finally this works :)

Answer (score 0):

```
//class writer to write file
def writer = new StringWriter();
//builder xml
def xmlCreated = new MarkupBuilder(writer);
//file where will be write the xml
def fileXmlOut = new File("C:\\Users\\example\\Desktop\\example\\test.xml");

//method MarkupBuilder to xml       
xmlCreated.mkp.xmlDeclaration(version: "1.0", encoding: "utf-8");
xmlCreated.playlist() {
    list() {
        //xml = your file xml parse
        name xml.list.name.text()
    }
    eventlist () {
        event(type: example.eventlist.@type)                   
    }
}
//writing xml in file
fileXmlOut << writer.toString();
```

Comment: can you explain it a bit?